# Facebook offline wall post action link is not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

Hi i created a new application in facebook with offline access permission. Application is working fine when i posting the wall information action link parameter is not shown

How to solve it....

And one more question when i post information some of the id's were not posted, exception error handling shows the message: FacebookErrorResponseException: Application request limit reached

How to fix it ....

Comment: (kind of a duplicate):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746159/post-as-link-type-with-facebook-graph-api/3759656#3759656

Answer (score 0):

Use the facebook API's available on codeplex.com and try this out,

```
        Facebook.Rest.attachment_media_image image1 = new attachment_media_image();

        image1.href = "";
        image1.src = "";

        Facebook.Rest.attachment a = new Facebook.Rest.attachment();
        a.media = new List<Facebook.Rest.attachment_media> { image1 };
        a.href = "";
        a.name = "";
        a.caption = "{*actor*}";
        a.properties = null;



        if(fbapi.Users.HasAppPermission(Enums.ExtendedPermissions.publish_stream))
         fbapi.Stream.Publish(" Your message, a,
                                new List<action_link>() { new action_link() 
                                { text = "",                                      
                                href ="" } 
                                },
                                null, 0);
```